# How to get only year, month,day,horus and seconds from Java JSpinner

Tags: java, swing, date, datetime, jspinner

I am working on my MySQL project and I have one problem. I have made one `JSpinner` that shows current date and time. Now I want to save that date and time in one `datetime` variable for later use, but problem is when I save value from JSpinner into my `datetime` variable its not in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. Instead of that my `datetime` variable contains this: 'Sat Aug 17 19:07:03 CEST 2013'. I want to save only numbers in classic 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format because my database on my server accepts only data in that format, but I dont know how to cast it. Please help!

Here is my code:

```
String datum_vrijeme;
SpinnerDateModel s1 = new SpinnerDateModel();
spinner1 = new JSpinner(s1);
JSpinner.DateEditor d1 = new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner1, "yyyy/MM/dd   HH:mm:ss");
spinner1.setEditor(d1);
Object sp = spinner1.getValue();
datum_vrijeme=sp.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `java.util.Date` object, which is one step closer to your MySQL database, instead of a String.

```
Date date = (Date) spinner1.getValue();
```

Comment: Sorry but I am using JDBC connector and I need to write my sql query so I need to have my datetime in string format so I can concatenate it with my string query to finally execute it to update my database row...

Comment: You should do as Martijn suggests, and pass the Date object as a parameter of a [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

Comment: @MahirDuraković: That is BAD practice! Search for PreparedStatements and SQL Injection and you will know why. Prepared Statements do support Date objects.

Comment: I tried your suggestions but I have same problem again. My Date variable is in this format: 'Sat Aug 17 19:07:03 CEST 2013', I want it in classic 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format

Comment: @Mahir Duraković have to test if required to convert util.Date to sql.Date or to Timestampt up to you. btw must be a bunch Q&A here about, note in all cases you need to separate logics for Swing (JSpinner), Java Essential Classes(util.Date) and JDBC (DateTime/Timestampt)